# Obtener al Id de una tabla

Tags: mysql, flutter

Estoy trabajando con flutter para una app y estoy necesitando sacar algunos datos ya guardados.

Estoy queriendo obtener de la base de datos la id y me esta saltando el siguiente problema.

Si sabrían alguna forma de transformar para que pueda obtener los datos.

Consola:

```
   lib/screens/profile.dart:49:40: Error: A value of type 'Object' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
        txtIdController.text =user!.id ??'';
```

profile.dart

```
User? user;
  bool loading = true;
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  File? _imageFile;
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  TextEditingController txtNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtemailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtPhoneController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txtIdController = TextEditingController();       //El Id

// get user detail
  void getUser() async {
    ApiResponse response = await getUserDetail();
    if (response.error == null) {
      setState(() {
        user = response.data as User;
        loading = false;
        txtNameController.text = user!.name ?? '';
        txtemailController.text = user!.email ?? '';
        txtPhoneController.text =user!.phone ??'';
        txtIdController.text =user!.id ??'';                 //aca es donde salta el error
      });
```

user.dart

```
class User {  int? id;
  String? name;
  String? phone;
  String? image;
  String? email;
  String? token;

  User({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.phone,
    this.image,
    this.email,
    this.token
  });
  }
}
```

Comment: Sí lees el fallo, verás que el mismo te está diciendo cuál es el problema.

Comment: Si pero nose como resolverlo ya intenté varias cosas pero sin resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sí te fijas, el tipo de dato de id, es `int`, el cual no puede ser asignado a un `String`. Te bastaría con hacer el `toString` de id.

Creo que sería algo así:
`user!.id?.toString() ?? ''`